# Sound not working on dell chromebook 11 3120 (Candy), showing dummy output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, chromebook

So I installed Ubuntu on this chromebook by installing Seabios and booting from a USB and erased ChromeOS. Once I booted, the only thing it showed in the sound settings was "Dummy Output", which didn't play any sound. If I plugged in my headphones, same thing. The only time it plays sound is through the HDMI port.

Here are some outputs:

pacmd list-cards

```
    $ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 6
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd0914000 irq 260"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "0f04"
    device.product.name = "Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <off>
ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

lspci -nnk | grep -i audio

```
    $ lspci -nnk | grep -i audio
    00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:0f04] (rev 0e)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:0f04]
```

If anyone has any ideas on what could help then I'm open to them.